# Is my code using multithreading in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to create a new thread for my app which will—of course—do all the necessary background work when I call it to prevent the UI thread from crashing. I cannot get it to work and am a little confused as to what I should do next. Here is my code:

```
package com.alarm.mobilegame;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class startGames extends MainActivity {

int a = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);          
int b = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
int c = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);          
int d = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
int e = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);           
int f = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
boolean A;
boolean B;
boolean C;

public void additionCalc() {

    TextView addquestion;
    TextView addquestion2;
    addquestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    addquestion2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    addquestion.setText("" + a + "+");
    addquestion2.setText("" + b);
}
public void substitutionCalc() {
    if (d > c)
    {
        while(d > c)
        d = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);              
    }
    TextView subquestion;
    TextView subquestion2;
    subquestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    subquestion2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    subquestion.setText("" + c + "-");
    subquestion2.setText("" + d);
}
public void multiplicationCalc() {
    if (e * f < 1)
    {
        while(e * f < 1)
        f = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);   
    }
    TextView mulquestion;
    TextView mulquestion2;
    mulquestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    mulquestion2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    mulquestion.setText("" + e + "x");
    mulquestion2.setText("" + f);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_game1);

    final Button buttonMathStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonMathStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) {
            additionCalc();
            substitutionCalc();
            multiplicationCalc();
        }});
}

void runInBackground() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            checkResultsA();
            checkResultsB();
            checkResultsC();
        }

            public void checkResultsA() {
                EditText aText;

                aText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                int c = Integer.parseInt(aText.toString());
                int d = a + b;
                if (d != c) {
                    A = false;
                }else{
                    A = true;
                    }
                }
                public void checkResultsB() {
                    EditText sText;
                    sText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    int c = Integer.parseInt(sText.toString());

                    int z = c - d;
                    if (d != c) {
                        B = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        B = true;
                        }
                    }
                public void checkResultsC() {
                    EditText mText;

                    mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    int c = Integer.parseInt(mText.toString());

                    int d = a * b;
                    if (d != c) {

                        C = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        C = true;
                    }  

            //runInBackground();
        }
    });


    Button continueGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    continueGame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            runInBackground();

            if (A || B || C == false)
            {
                //
            }
            else
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(startGames.this, secondGame.class);
                startGames.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        }});
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I dont think you should create a thread for such a trivial task.. You will not be gaining any advantage by using a thread here..

Comment: It crashes otherwise, can you see why that would be caused? The user enters three numbers and I want to validate them like above, it crashes so I want to put the validators into a new thread to stop UI thread from crashing.

Comment: @AndrewStewart : I think laalto's answer is the one you are looking for...

Answer (score 4):

Your `runInBackground()` creates a `Thread` but does not `start()` it. The code is never run.

The thread code seems to be accessing UI elements. Generally you shouldn't touch the UI in a background thread.

Where you invoke `runInBackground()` in `onClick()` you seem to assume the thread result is already available on the next code line. It isn't.

I suggest you have a look at the `AsyncTask` to make background thread operations easier. It also has convenience helpers for working with the UI thread.

Also, based on the question comments it seems that you don't need a background thread in the first place. The root problem is the crash which you avoid by not running your code. To get help with the crash, have a look at exception stacktrace in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the thread but seems you forgot to add code for starting the thread.
Change your runInBackground method to

```
void runInBackground() {
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        checkResultsA();
        checkResultsB();
        checkResultsC();
    }

        public void checkResultsA() {
            EditText aText;

            aText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            int c = Integer.parseInt(aText.toString());
            int d = a + b;
            if (d != c) {
                A = false;
            }else{
                A = true;
                }
            }
            public void checkResultsB() {
                EditText sText;
                sText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                int c = Integer.parseInt(sText.toString());

                int z = c - d;
                if (d != c) {
                    B = false;
                }
                else{
                    B = true;
                    }
                }
            public void checkResultsC() {
                EditText mText;

                mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                int c = Integer.parseInt(mText.toString());

                int d = a * b;
                if (d != c) {

                    C = false;
                }
                else {
                    C = true;
                }  

        //runInBackground();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I have updated my code but my application when I click my button, it crashes, "stopped unexpectedly", any clue as to why this would happen?

Comment: add your stack trace.